# Excel doesn't calculate anymore

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't have a clue what happened. Excel stopt calculating.

The only thing i did was applying a filter, which is not active anymore.

This is an example

value R76 = 200

value H76 = =R76*1,06

Outcome = #value! Beats me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your percentage(?) value has a decimal comma rather than a decimal point.

Have you changed the language on your spreadsheet so that it's now expecting a decimal point?

Comment: your answer brought me to the sollution. The prices I import from a csv file are for example 112.95, when I changed it to 112,95 it started calculating again.

Answer (score 0):

try 1.06 instead of 1,06

Comment: when I do that, the formula stays on H76 (=R2*1.06)